# ScrollViewDidScroll causes exc_bad_access code 2 error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view controller that presents a collectionView. When some of the cells are touched within the collectionView, they are to load a view onto the screen. Some of the cells load their view just fine, while others crash and I get an exc_bad_access code 2 at this part of the code.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if([_scrollViewDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollViewDidScroll:)]){
        [_scrollViewDelegate scrollViewDidScroll:scrollView];
    }
}
```

Here is the init method in which the delegates for the scrollView are set.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame collectionViewLayout:[self standardCollectionViewLayout]];
    if(!self.collectionViewLayout)
        self.collectionViewLayout = [self standardCollectionViewLayout];
    self.delegate = self;
    self.dataSource = self;
    self.hasSetLayout = false;
    [self setScrollViewDelegate:self];

    return self;
}
```

In an attempt to debug this problem, I have synthesized the delegate property and setup separate setter and getter methods.

```
-(void)setScrollViewDelegate:(id<UIScrollViewDelegate>)scrollViewDelegate{
    if (scrollViewDelegate != nil){
        _scrollViewDelegate = scrollViewDelegate;
    }
}

-(id<UIScrollViewDelegate>)scrollViewDelegate{
    if (_scrollViewDelegate != nil){
        return _scrollViewDelegate;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

EDIT: Just tried out using ScrollViewDidEndDragging:WillDecelerate: and this method does not cause a crash.

Comment: What's in your collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:?

Comment: Try to set the delegate to nil in `dealloc`.